# How to include a worker/process file with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a file that creates child processes, the code is similar to this:

```
var cp = require('child_process');

function process () {
  return cp.fork('./worker');
}

module.exports(process);
```

But `./worker` doesn't seem to be included in the bundle. Which causes the following error when running the `process` function:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\GitHub\PROJECT\worker'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^
```

How can I make sure worker files are bundled as well? I want my whole project in óne file.

Answer (score 4):

There is a possible workaround. You can copy all your worker files into the dist directory. Let us say you have all your worker files in a `workers` directory. And so your above code changes a little (includes worker.js from workers direcotory).

```
var cp = require('child_process');
function process () {
  return cp.fork('./workers/worker');
}

module.exports(process);
```

And to copy the workers folder to your build/dist folder, you can use [copy-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin). In your case the plugin can be used like this in the webpack config file.

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
```

// your configuration for entry and output will be different, of course
        entry: './main.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'dist/bundle.js'
        },
        target: 'node',
        plugins: [
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                {
                    from: 'workers',
                    to: 'dist/workers'
                }
            ])
        ]
    }

Your bundle will still not have the worker.js file, but the reference will work for `fork` method.

Comment: This works, but it still requires a user to download multiple files instead of just óne bundle.

Comment: How are you planning to use the bundle? Is it a library?

Comment: It's [a library](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic) for Node.js and browsers. For Node it wouldn't really be a problem, but it is weird for browsers to need multiple cdn links for óne library.

Comment: But can you run child_process.fork in a browser?

Comment: noo... sadly I did not think about this. Still, I don't like the idea of having multiple build files. But I'm definitely going to use your answer if no other answer appears.